# Deploy to Style Library and Publishing Images using WSP from Visual Studio

Tags: solution-package, branding

Is it possible to deploy some default files to folders like Style Library and Publishing Images from a SharePoint project created on Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. You create a module which points to the corresponding articfact.

More about it here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2009/11/23/how-to-deploy-a-style-sheet-into-content-library-using-visual-studio-2010-beta-2.aspx

//M